# Remove Map from Vector when same keys exist in another Vector

Tags: clojure

I have the following data structure (two Vectors of Maps I believe)

```
{ :put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1", :dateTime 1434637074},
        {:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
  :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]}
```

and would like to remove any `:put` entries for which the keys `listId` and `entryId` already exist inside `:delete`. The result should therefore be:

```
{ :put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
  :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]}
```

I have tried the following but 1) it's not idiomatic Clojure and 2) it doesn't delete the duplicate entry.

```
(defn remove-add-if-duplicate [requests]
  (doseq [delete (seq (:delete requests))]
    (doseq [put (seq (:put requests)) 
            :when (and (= (:listId delete) (:listId put))
                       (= (:entryId delete) (:entryId put))]
      (disj (set (:put requests)) put)))
  requests))

(remove-add-if-duplicate 
  { :put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1", :dateTime 1434637074},
          {:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
    :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]})
```

Can you help me fix my code or show me a nice way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn strip [data]
  (let [ks (-> data :delete set)]
    (update-in data [:put] #(remove (fn [m] (ks (select-keys m [:listId :entryId]))) %))))
```

For example, ...

```
(def my-stuff { :put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1", :dateTime 1434637074},
        {:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
  :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]})

(def processed { :put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
  :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]})

(= (strip my-stuff) processed);
;true
```

This is essentially the same as [McSokoli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703473/1562315), but

- presented as a function,
- using a set rather than `some` to test for presence,
- using `update-in` to apply to the whole data structure.

---

You have misunderstood the way that Clojure's data structures work. The functions that handle them don't change them; instead, they return a modified version.

Your use of `doseq` is a giveaway. This returns `nil`, so only has side effects, of which there are none in this case; nor ought there to be.

You could use `for` with `:where` to get the effect of `remove`, but there's no point.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.
We use `select-keys` to keep only the keys (and their values) `:listId` and `:entryId` from entries in `:put` from the input, and `remove` such entries that are found in `(:delete input)`.

```
(def input {:put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1", :dateTime 1434637074},
                  {:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}],
            :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}]}


(defn filtered [input]
  {:delete (:delete input)
   :put (remove #(some #{(select-keys % [:listId :entryId])} 
               (:delete input))    
        (:put input))})
```

Testing it we get this:

```
user> (filtered input)
{:delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}], 
 :put ({:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075})}
```

or with more data

```
user> (filtered {:put [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1", :dateTime 1434637074},
                       {:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}
                       {:listId "other", :entryId "3", :dateTime 1434637076}
                       {:listId "bestList", :entryId "4", :dateTime 1434637076}],
                :delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"}
                         {:listId "bestList" :entryId "4"}]})
{:delete [{:listId "myList", :entryId "1"} {:listId "bestList", :entryId "4"}],
 :put ({:listId "myList", :entryId "2", :dateTime 1434637075}
       {:listId "other", :entryId "3", :dateTime 1434637076})}
```